# Continuity of a function theory

Tags: limits, proof-verification, continuity, proof-explanation

If $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $ \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,y)=0  $
then $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$?

My teacher said this was true but if you take a function by parts this can be false right?

Comment: If $f(0,0)=0$ then this is true by the definition of continuity.

Comment: What do you mean by "Take a function by parts"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = 0$ means that
$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta >0 : d((x,y),(0,0)) < \delta \Rightarrow d(f(x,y),0) < \epsilon$. Presumably we have $f(0,0) = 0$, then indeed $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. This is simply the definition of being continuous in a point.

Note that this necessarily implies that 
$$
\lim_{y \to 0} f(0,y) =  \lim_{x \to 0} f(x,0) =0.
$$
But the converse doesn't hold as you mention (or at least that's how I interpreted it), meaning that a function can satisfy the above condition but still be discontinuous in $(0,0)$. Consider for example the following function

$$
f(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{xy}{x^2 +y^2} & \text{ if } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
0 & \text{ if } (x,y) = (0,0)\end{matrix}\right.
$$

In this case we obviously have
$$
\lim_{y \to 0} f(0,y) =  \lim_{x \to 0} f(x,0) =0.
$$
But if we approach $(0,0)$ from the straight line $y=x$, so
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x,x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{2x^2} = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
Thus the function $f$ isn't continuous at $0$.